# jekyll: content in one big paragraph on index page

Tags: jekyll, liquid

On an index page, I have the following liquid code:

```
{% for entry in site.posts %}
    {{ entry.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Seems like the simplest code possible. Display a list of posts. And it works, but the `{{entry.content}}` isn't being processed. It's just the raw markdown in one big lump.

Individual posts, that is using `{{ content }}` inserts the proper formatting, but `{{ entry.content }}` does not.

I'm at a loss to explain what's happening here. How do I get the markdown processed for index pages?

The site is using `redcarpet` for markdown processing, which might be relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I instantly answered my own question.

I was using `jekyll serve --incremental`, which was causing the problem. If I change the layout for a page with `--incremental` on, Jekyll will start vomiting up raw markdown on a page refresh. If I kill the server and re-run it, even with `--incremental` on, everything is fine...until I change the layout again.

Probably a bug?

This is all on Jekyll 3.1.2

Comment: Yup, I too had flaky output from using `incremental`. :(